# pv not printing to a pipe

Tags: pipe, pv

Executing this command displays the output on console. But when output is piped to another command it does not work. See below.

```
(pv -F $'%t %r %e\n' /dev/nvme0n1p1 | gzip -c >/run/test.img ) 
0:00:01 [25.2MiB/s] ETA 0:00:18
0:00:02 [23.7MiB/s] ETA 0:00:18
0:00:03 [ 100MiB/s] ETA 0:00:07
0:00:04 [ 199MiB/s] ETA 0:00:01
```

Now see below same command output is piped to another command and it does not display anything at all. I have redirected stderr to stdout and passed it to tr -d so it can remove ":[ ] " characters.

```
(pv -F $'%t %r %e\n' /dev/nvme0n1p1 | gzip -c >/run/test.img ) 2>&1 | tr -d ':[]'
```

See below, same command, but I am not redirecting stderr to stdout, Also if I don't redirect stderr to stdout, with the same command above, I don't get desired results, see below, using tr -d to delete following characters ":[]" but does not work. You can see tr -d command is completely ignored.

```
(pv -F $'%t %r %e\n' /dev/nvme0n1p1 | gzip -c >/run/test.img ) | tr -d ':[]'
0:00:01 [25.2MiB/s] ETA 0:00:18
0:00:02 [23.7MiB/s] ETA 0:00:18
0:00:03 [ 100MiB/s] ETA 0:00:07
0:00:04 [ 199MiB/s] ETA 0:00:01
```

I have spent countless hours to figure this out, searched on stackexchange and all the forums but I cannot get my head around, how to fix this.

I have also tried using file Descriptor 2>&3 but still no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pv -f …`

From [`man 1 pv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html):

> `-f`, `--force`
> Force output. Normally, `pv` will not output any visual display if standard error is not a terminal. This option forces it to do so.

```
(pv -fF $'%t %r %e\n' /dev/nvme0n1p1 | gzip -c >/run/test.img ) 2>&1 | tr -d ':[]'
```